# How do I fix a white space error following a citation?

Tags: python, pycharm, latex, bibtex

I'm using latex in Python (Pycharm IDE) to write my thesis. The error I am getting

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.8)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
White space in argument---line 121 of file main.aux
 : \citation{turt
 :                Santra2017}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: main-blx.bib
Database file #2: library.bib
Biblatex version: 3.16
(There was 1 error message)
bibtex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

While doing citations with \parencite, I had accidentally made a typo, which I later corrected. The typo was \parencite{turt Santra2017} - as shown in the error.

Even after fixing the typo, restarting Pycharm several times, even deleting this reference entirely, I am still getting this exact same error preventing me from compiling my .tex.

The compiler is pdfLatex, Sumatra PDF viewer, LaTeX distribution is MiKTex.

Any ideas of other ways to troubleshoot this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably have a few files that contain the reference in a cache. Did you remove all non-essential files?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I was thinking it must be cache related problem, but I don't know how to clear it. Could you let me know how to remove non-essential files? Many thanks!

Comment: My LaTeX is a bit rusty, but something like the .aux, .log and .toc files you can remove safely in the folder where your .tex/.bib file lives.

Comment: Many thanks, I found in auxil/main.aux still the old version of the reference and fixed it, now it works ! PS: Clearing the  PyCharm cache or deleting files from dir/main.aux didn't help (in case someone encounters this and has similar problem).